# Carrierwave duplicating with thumbs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

guys.

How I can copy one model to another with thumbs?

I use just

```
new_image.image = File.open(old_image.image.current_path)
```

But thumbs, that was cutted before, make from scratch. What I can do?

Answer (score 0):

You want to duplicate a model without having to re-generate thumbs? CarrierWave doesn't provide an API to do this, so you're going to have to do it by hand, which could be a pain. You may be better off just letting carrierwave re-generate the thumbs.

Comment: But... If thumbs are cutting versions and carrierwave don't know how to cut them? What I can do?

BTW, why carrierwave don't provide an API for this?

Comment: I don't think I know what you mean by "thumbs cutting versions".

Comment: I mean that user edit files, and I don't know how. So, if I have don't copy a thumb versions, I'll loose their editings

Comment: If the user is editing it, in CarrierWave terms, it should be another Uploader, not just a Version. Versions are supposed to be automatically generated.